# Laravel - How to replace a string in database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a blog website. I change my brand name. So I  need to change all blog posts that include my brand name.

I can find them like :

```
$search = 'old-brand-name';
$posts = \App\Models\BlogPost::where('description', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')->get();
```

But I have to replace these strings in database level with my new brand name. How I can do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should iterate each post and then change the description by replacing old_brand_name by new_brand_name and update this post.

```
foreach($posts as $post){
    $old_des = $post->description;
    $post->description = str_replace($search,'new-brand-name', $post->description);
    $post->save();
}
```

Hope it can help you

Comment: It should be `foreach()`.

Comment: Why would you even select - just update the whole thing anyway

Comment: @Insax According to his Where clause in the expression, I think the description contains string 'old-brand-name` but not equal exactly. Therefore, we should replace all `old-brand-name` in description and update it

Comment: @DuyHuynh yes you are totally right, I overlooked that.

Comment: Updates like this complete faster using query builder.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62273870/700439).

Comment: str_replace is not working in Laravel6.0 , instead it works with Str:: but Str::replace is nothing, any other way?

Answer (score 3):

You can find/replace string values in a single transaction using [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries).

```php
$oldBrandName = 'Acme Co';
$newBrandName = 'Bar Co';

DB::update(
  'update blog_posts set description = replace(description, ?, ?) where description like ?',
  [
     $oldBrandName,
     $newBrandName,
     $search
  ]
);
```

Comment: Where does the variable `$search` get defined / what is it?

Comment: @crazy-coders defined a `$search` variable in their question.  In reality `$search` would be replaced with something like a request parameter, or a function parameter, etc.

Answer (score 3):

i know this might be an old question but you can also do this

```
\App\Models\BlogPost::where('description', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
   ->update([
      $column => DB::raw("REPLACE($column,'$search','$replace')") 
    ]);
```

Comment: use  regexp_replace($column,'$search','$replace','i'); 
for case-insensitively

Comment: you might want to do replace($column::text,....
if the field is not text/string

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mysql Replace, it will replace all occurence of chars into a table column :

`update posts set description = REPLACE(description,'old','new');`

It's more efficient because you don't have to query all the occurrences of your results to replace your chars.

Segundo, use collection callbacks instead of foreach, it's more readable and perf friendly. (like map, reduce, ect..)

Answer (score 0):

```
$search = 'old-brand-name';
$posts = \App\Models\BlogPost::where('description', $search)->update('description', $newName);
```

This only works if the content of your 'description' column is exactly your brand name, otherwise you have to give more specific information about the content in the description column.

Comment: yes it's not a problem. it will be ok if i can replace these strings with my new brand name

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update all posts and get all results :

```
$old   = 'old-brand-name';
$new   = 'new-brand-name';
$posts = \App\Models\BlogPost::where('description', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($item) use ($old, $new) {
        $item->description = str_replace($old, $new, $item->description);
        $item->save();

        return $item;
    });

// Print all
dd($posts->toArray());
```